# How to kill or Stop an I/O requesting thread in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading, io

How to kill or Stop an I/O requesting thread in JAVA?

I'm trying to stop a thread which is playing an mp3 file. Now I want to stop this thread so that I can stop playing the mp3 file on my click.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in the beginning of the threads' invocation, and when the user clicks the button change the flag to `false`. Something in the lines of:

```
    private volatile boolean flag;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.flag = true;
        while (this.flag) {
            try {
                // mp3 playing code goes here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                this.flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
```